# vue.js vue-good-table passing id to laravel controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Hello guys I'm new to vue.js and vue-good-table.

I was able to get the id of my row data using console.log but I don't know how to pass it to the controller in order to proceed with a put or delete method.

**Department.vue Component**

```
<vue-good-table styleClass="vgt-table striped bordered condensed" 
....>
 <template slot="table-row" slot-scope="props">
  <span v-if="props.column.field == 'before'">
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" @click="fetch(props)">Edit</button>
  </span>
</template>
</vue-good-table>

<script>
...
...
  methods: {
      fetch(props) {
            console.log(props.row.id);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should use the HTTP client _(axios, ajax, etc)_ of your choice to construct a request to the server.

So, inside the `fetch()` you should do something like that `this.axios.delete('/endpoint/to/call', {...}, {data: {id: props.row.id}})`. _(Please keep in mind that the code example I used above should change based on your setup. You can't use it as a final solution)_.

Comment: I tried this one in the component fetch(id) {
          axios.delete(`/api/department/${id}`)
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }   and here is my controller:   $article = Department::findOrFail($id);
    $article->delete(); but I'm encountering a 500 internal server error

Comment: My bad my route 'DeparttmentController@delete' instead of  DpeartmentController@destroy. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You may use any ajax library to reach the goal.
For example axios
In your project folder do

```
npm install axios --save
```

In your component add

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Then just read the documentation and do requests to your controller https://github.com/axios/axios